# Dropdown showing Duplicate Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, dropdown

I have 4 Dropdown and i am using one Database table for binding Dropdown. But in Dropdown i am getting duplicate values. I used Distinct in select statement but i amnot gettng unique value because it has 4 column.

So is there any way to get unique values or anyway to not getting duplicate value.

Comment: Can you please add your dropdowns binding c# code in the question!

Comment: It is simple binding, first i used query and stored in datatable, then give source to dropdown, give the column name for text and bind, did same thing for all with different column. As of now i am in home so i am not be able to share code.

Comment: It would be alot easier to find a solution and fix your code, do share the code when you are in office, it should be a simple and quick fix I believe.

Comment: Ok i will share the code with you on Monday

Answer (score 0):

If

- there are 4 columns
- you applied `DISTINCT`

how did you manage to get duplicates? What duplicates? `DISTINCT` removes them, so there shouldn't be any rows where those 4 values match.

A blind guess: if you want to get distinct values for one of those columns and don't care about the rest of them, then something like this might help:

```
select 
  id,                     --> this is that "unique" value you're looking for
  max(name),              --> use one of aggregates for the rest of columns, ...
  max(address),           --> ... such as MAX in my example
  max(phone)
from your_table
group by id               --> as aggregates require GROUP BY, you don't need DISTINCT
```

If it still doesn't help, I'm afraid you'll have to explain the problem better. Don't forget to provide test case.

Comment: I hav 4 column and i am binding 4 column in 4 different dropdown. In Database values are like :- Column 1- A,B,C,A,A | Column 2-D,E,F,F,G | Column 3-K,L,M,N,O

Answer (score 0):

Distinct() needs to know how to tell if an item in your collection matches another item.
Try something like this.

```
items.Distinct((itemA, itemB) => string.Equals(
    itemA.Name, itemB.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Binding. You should bind only

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   //Put the logic for the Dropdown DataBind here
}
```

If you don't do this you get a new set of Dropdown values with each postback and that's how you got the duplicate values.
If it is not the Binding could you post your SQL statement?

Comment: Actually i have 4 dropdown and i am getting data from database. In every drpdwn i am using different column. So in database i have duplicate value this is the reason for duplication. I used distinct but it is not working.

Comment: What if you do 4 different select statements. I mean 1 with just the value you want to use and DataBind that to the appropriate dropdown list. That should work ok with distinct.

Comment: This is working, as i am new in programming line. So i am thinking is there any way to do it by hitting database one time.

Comment: That's what you do as I posted in my initial answer. Do the call to the database within an If(!IsPostback). Then you hit the database only once. You can DataBind each dropdown list from that one single database table.

Comment: All code in !isPostback, but the problem is some column in database have duplicate value and distinct is not giving distinct value of 4 column. I have to use separate select query for all dropdown. So i am asking is this only option or we can do it in any better way.

Comment: I would do 4 database queries. Each for its purpose. As I don't know your data it's more difficult to tell. You could load the data into a new DataTable and then use that DataTable to populate 4 more DataTables which don't have the duplicate values. Then bind those new ones to the dropdownlist.

Comment: I will try this and also i will share the code with you